# How to disable HTTP request if data for one of the variable is not present in csv file

Tags: jmeter

csv file:

TC-24;Name=myName1;{ "Name": "myName1" }

TC-25;Name=myName2;

TC-26;Name=myName3;{ "Name": "myName3" }

I created if controller and set "${namejson}" != null . Under if controller I added HTTP request. This request should create object if json is present in csv file

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How to disable HTTP request if data for one of the variable is not present in csv file

Comment: Why do you have to disable when it is already inside the if controller? can you show your csv file as well?

Comment: My csv file is added. It contains from  test case number, param=value and json. All these data are variables. First of all I should to create something by sending json in body (one HTTP request). After that I should to search this using param=value  (Name=myName1 ) in path (another HTTP request). The problem is that I dont need to create reqest for second case because json is not present. Thats why I should to miss this step. I can't do it

Answer (score 3):

This is because if your `${namejson}` variable is not defined, If Controller sees it literally as `${namejson}` which is not null.

Use the following condition:

```
${__javaScript(vars.get("namejson") != null,)}
```

`vars` is a shorthand to [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance available via [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Scripting_Java) (or Nashorn) which provides read/write access to [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html).

See [How to Use JMeter's 'IF' Controller and get Pie](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie) for more tips and tricks.